# Pigeonhole Principle problem on the inequality of the sums of two subsets

Tags: problem-solving, pigeonhole-principle

Good day, this problem is designed to use the Pigeonhole Principle.
For a finite set A of integers, denote by $s(A)$ the sum of numbers in $A$.
Let S be a subset of {$1,2,3,...,14, 15$} such that $s(B) \neq s(C)$ for any
2 disjoint subsets B,C of S. Show that $|S| \leq5$.

I proved that for $|S| \geq 7$ such subsets exist. Since the number of non-empty subsets are $2^7-2=126$, and the possible sums are  $1\leq s(A)\leq 15+14+13+12+11+10=75$.

And then, according to the Pigeonhole Principle , putting $126$ sets into $75$ boxes of sums, there will be two sums such that $s(A)=s(B)$. But for $|S|=6$ this method doesn't work. It seems to me that if you prove for $|S|=6$, then for $|S| \leq 5$ it will become obvious.

Comment: I can't follow your argument.  If I have a general subset $S$ of $[15]=\{1, \cdots, 15\}$, and a subset $A\subset S$, how do I know that $s(A)<75$?  The whole set $[15]$ certainly contains subsets that sum over that.

Comment: A subset is not $\ge 7$ but its **cardinality** is. So, please replace $S \ge 7$ with $|S| \ge 7$.

Comment: @lulu A is the  subset of S and since the sets  do not intersect (that is, A cannot be equal to S), then the maximum possible number of elements in A is 6 and the maximum possible sum of these elements is the sum of the maximum elements from S

Comment: @didenkojack You don't know $\lvert S\rvert=7$ yet, only $\lvert S\rvert\geq 7$.  The correct way is to count the possible subset sums $s(A)$, that turns out to between $0$ to $105$ inclusive, so still below $2^7\leq\lvert\mathscr{P}(S)$ possibilities.

Comment: Ok, so you are assuming that $|S|=7$?  You didn't say that.  And, of course, $A$ could equal $\{10,11,12,13,14,15\}$ in  which case $s(A)=75$.  But, most seriously, most of the pairs of subsets of $S$ would fail to be disjoint so you have to argue that this doesn't matter.  N.B. I believe you can argue that, but as it stands, that's a gap in your argument.

Comment: Do you have an example of a subset of order $5$ for which the property holds?

Comment: @lulu  You are right, sorry about that, it’s really worth adding that if $B\cap C  \neq \emptyset $ , then the sum will still be equal for $B/B\cap C  $and $C /B\cap C $

Comment: And are you sure the argument doesn't go through for $|S|=6$?  there are $2^6-2=62$ proper subsets of $S$ and the largest a sum of $5$ numbers could be is $11+12+\cdots+15=65$ which is awfully close.  Noting that $65$ is impossible (as such a sum is unique given the constraints) you just need to eliminate a small number of other sums to finish.  Assuming you have a winning example for $|S|=5$.

Comment: Can you check the original phrasing? Is it "less than 15" or do you know for certain that you allow for 15 to be in the subset S?

Comment: Yes, this is true, but we must also exclude the subsets corresponding to this sum

Comment: @didenkojack You just have to check those small number of cases, and then you are done. What subsets do we have to consider?

Comment: FYI Slight error with " Since the number of non-empty subsets are $2^7−\color{red} 1 $".

Comment: Yes, that’s right, I also excluded a subset equal to the set itself

Comment: @lulu We don't need a subset of order 5 for which the property holds in order to prove the statement. There is such an example though, with largest element 13.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on $|S| = 6$, as OP did $|S| \geq 7$.

First. see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003076/applying-the-pigeonhole-principle-to-a-set-of-subsets) for how to deal with the case when $S$ is a subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, \color{red}{14} \}$.
Naive PP gives us subset sums of 0 to 69, with only $2^6 = 64$ subsets, so it doesn't apply.
The refining idea is reduce the possible subset sums by considering the maximal difference between non-empty subsets of $S$, which is at most $10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 = 60$, so there are at most 61 distinct possible non-empty-subset-sums. Since there are $2^6 - 1 = 63$ non-empty subsets, hence by PP, some two non-empty-subsets have the same sum.
(Read their solution if you need more details. Note: In a similar vein, other restrictions like "subsets with 2 or 3 elements" could work for similar problems.)

Back to this problem: When we apply this idea to the case when $S$ is a subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, 15 \}$, if the maximal difference is 61 or lower, then we can apply PP per the above. However, since $11+12+13+14+15 = 65$, we have to take care of certain cases.
Consider what the 5 largest values of $S$ are, in order to get a maximal difference of 62 or higher. Show that they must be one of  (I believe I got all cases, if not please let me know.)

- $\{15, 14, 13, 12, 11 \}$,
- $\{15, 14, 13, 12, 10 \}$,
- $\{15, 14, 13, 12, 9 \}$,
- $\{15, 14, 13, 12, 8 \}$,
- $\{15, 14, 13, 11, 10 \}$,
- $\{15, 14, 13, 11, 9 \}$,
- $\{15, 14, 12, 11, 10 \}$

For each case, we can easily find a conflicting subset sum from these 5 elements alone, by focusing on terms that differ by 1 or 2.  Hence we are done.

---

With some tedious checking, $S=\{6, 9, 11, 12,13 \}$ has distinct subset sums. So we cannot strengthen the result further.